# How to determine if the following function subsets from $\mathbb{R}$ are vector subspaces (beginner)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

As per the title, I wish to determine which of the following subsets from $\mathbb{R}$ are vector subspaces.

I have consulted [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200134/is-this-subset-a-subspace) related question, and I understand that three criteria need to be fulfilled. (namely, the 0 element is contained, the set is closed und addition and the set is closed under multiplication). Nonetheless, the notation below isn't intuitive to me. Below I have provided two subsets, as I think that the two examples are complimentary for forming an understanding.

$U_1 := \{ (x,y,z) | 3x - 4y + 2z = 0, x + 2y - z = 0\}$

...

$U_4 := \{ (2t + s, s, t-s) | s,t \in \mathbb{R}\}$

Any help in understanding the notation would be appreciated.

Thanks

---

EDIT: It has been pointed out that the following proposed solution is wrong.

Proposed solution for $U_4$:

I) Subset contains the 0 element:

If $s = 0, s \in \mathbb{R} = 0.$

$s = 0  \land 2t + s = 0 \implies t \in \mathbb{R} = 0.$

II) Subset is closed under addition:

If $s = 0 \land t = 0$, then $s + t = 0$.

III) Subset is closed under multiplication:

If $s = 0 \land \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ then $\lambda s = 0$

If $t = 0 \land \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ then $\lambda t = 0$

Answer (score 1):

What's preventing you from checking the three conditions? In the case of $U_1$:

1. Since $3\times0-4\times0+2\times0=0+2\times0-0=0$, $(0,0,0)\in U_1$.
2. If $3x_1-4y_1+2z_1=3x_2-4y_2+2z_2=0$, then $3(x_1+x_2)-4(y_1+y_2)+2(z_1+z_2)=0$. Also, if $x_1+2y_1-z_1=x_2+2y_2-z_2=0$, then $x_1+x_2+2(y_1+y_2)-(z_1+z_2)=0$
3. If $3x_1-4y_1+2z_1=x_1+2y_1-z_1=0$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb R$, $3\lambda x_1-4\lambda y_1+2\lambda z_1=\lambda(3x_1-4y_1+2z_1)=0$ and $\lambda x_1+2\lambda y_1-\lambda z_1=\lambda(x_1+2y_1-z_1)=0$.

Can you do it now for $U_4$?

Comment: The way i understand your solution, the left hand side (LHS) of the notation contains the variables, and the right hand side represents a transformation of those variables. Is this correct? If so, for U_4 i might represent the transformation "s" as 2(s) + 1(t - s), setting both (s) and (t-s) as 0.

Comment: @Oscar I did not think in terms of variables or of transformations. All I did was to check that: 1) $(0,0,0)\in U_1$. 2) $(x_1,y_1,z_1),(x_2,y_2,z_2)\in U_1\implies(x_1,y_1,z_1)+(x_2,y_2,z_2)\in U_1$. 3) $(x_1,y_1,z_1)\in U_1\text{ and }\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\implies\lambda(x_1,y_1,z_1)\in U_1$

Comment: Yes i understand. Would you mind telling me what is being represented on the left hand side and right hand side of the vertical line?

Comment: @Oscar What are talking about? $U_1$? $U_4$? Both of them?

Comment: Both of them. Also, I think I have shown that U_4 is indeed a vector subspace. I'll just edit my answer with my proposed solution.

Comment: @Oscar For instance, in the case of $U_1$ we are talking of all triplets $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $3x-4y+2z=x+2y-z=0$.

Comment: I Have edited my question to contain my proposed solution for the set $U_4$

Comment: @Oscar It's completely wrong. Your proposed solution isn't about $U_4$ at all. Where is $(2t+s,s,t-s)$ ever mentioned?

Comment: I'm affraid I must have misunderstood. If $(2t + s, s, t-s) = (a,b,c)$, I tried to use combinations of $b$ & $c$ to make statements about the RHS of $U_4$